# Getting IOS development build error

Tags: ios, codenameone

Development build get the following error during export, it shows that archive succeeded.  Also the app store distribution build passes.  I used the cert tool to generate all certs for this.

The full build log is here:
[Build log](https://s3.amazonaws.com/codenameone-build-response/df6c9fd4-c933-4d1a-b3e8-92ad0ee03cca-1513260359151-error.txt)

Here is the messages that look like the cause of the failure:

```
** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED **

Executing: echo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath rvgame.xcarchive -exportPath /var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/build4175955742863989776xxx/result -exportOptionsPlist /var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/export4912377426492049316.plist -verbose PROVISIONING_PROFILE=4b697edf-96fe-4b7a-ae88-07eaa148026f CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=iPhone Developer: samuel lotti (V8JNGG63WU) KEYCHAIN=/Users/administrator/Library/Keychains/temp1513260206451.keychain CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS=/var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/Entitlements4983206492678257794.plist /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath rvgame.xcarchive -exportPath /var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/build4175955742863989776xxx/result -exportOptionsPlist /var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/export4912377426492049316.plist -verbose PROVISIONING_PROFILE=4b697edf-96fe-4b7a-ae88-07eaa148026f CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=iPhone Developer: samuel lotti (V8JNGG63WU) KEYCHAIN=/Users/administrator/Library/Keychains/temp1513260206451.keychain CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS=/var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/Entitlements4983206492678257794.plist
Executing: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath rvgame.xcarchive -exportPath /var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/build4175955742863989776xxx/result -exportOptionsPlist /var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/export4912377426492049316.plist -verbose PROVISIONING_PROFILE=4b697edf-96fe-4b7a-ae88-07eaa148026f CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=iPhone Developer: samuel lotti (V8JNGG63WU) KEYCHAIN=/Users/administrator/Library/Keychains/temp1513260206451.keychain CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS=/var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/Entitlements4983206492678257794.plist 2017-12-14 08:05:38.785 xcodebuild[42364:31715511] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/rvgame_2017-12-14_08-05-38.784.xcdistributionlogs'.
2017-12-14 08:05:38.825 xcodebuild[42364:31715511] [MT] DeveloperPortal: Using pre-existing current store at URL (file:///Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DeveloperPortal%207.3.1.db).
2017-12-14 08:05:59.053 xcodebuild[42364:31715511] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: : Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=14 "No applicable devices found." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No applicable devices found.}
error: exportArchive: No applicable devices found.

Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=14 "No applicable devices found." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No applicable devices found.}

** EXPORT FAILED **
```

Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: It looks like you checked the `ios.includePush` option in the GUI but didn't activate it in the provisioning as far as I can tell.  But I'm not sure. Was the certificate/provisioning generated with the wizard? Did you successfully build in the past? Notice that they expire annually and need to be regenerated.

Comment: I did have the wizard generate them, but didn't have it generate the push cert since I have a current production push cert.  There is no development push cert. The profiles both support push.  If I let the wizard generate push will it revoke my old one.  I dont want that to happen.

Comment: On a hunch, try setting the ios.pods.platform build hint.  E.g. `ios.pods.platform=7.0` and see if that fixes the error

Comment: Also, please try to temporarily remove the flurry cn1lib (and comment out code that uses it), and see if it builds ok then.  It is possible that the Flurry cn1lib needs to be updated to use Cocoapods.

Comment: I tried ios.pods.platform, not help.
Removed flurry, not help.
Removed admob and can now build.
Maybe flurry and admob need to be updated?
How can these get updated?

Comment: @stevehannah please see the comments above.  I also tried updating the plugins to the latest and still has the issue.  Deleting them allows to build to pass and run on my ios device.  For some reason the release build was working but the development build was failing.

Comment: Is it both flurry and admob? Are you using the admob lib or the builtin support? Can you please include your android.* build hints?

Comment: Thanks.  I see what's going on.  The static libs for both of those cn1libs were compiled with an older version of Xcode, which didn't add some metadata that the current ipatool (part of xcodebuild) now expects.  We'll need to fix this in the cn1libs.

Comment: For reference http://thomask.sdf.org/blog/2015/09/15/xcode-7s-new-linker-rules.html

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem with new Xcode requirements on static libraries.  The Admob and Flurry static libs were compiled with an older version of Xcode which didn't include LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS run commands, and ipatool now crashes if it encounters a library that doesn't include this.

I have updated both the Admob and the Flurry cn1libs to use Cocoapods instead of the static library directly, and this will fix the issue.  These will be available in Codename One Settings after the next server update (this week).  If you need them before then, you can download and install the cn1libs directly:

- https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOneLibs/raw/master/cn1libs/CN1Flurry.cn1lib
- https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOneLibs/raw/master/cn1libs/AdmobFullScreen.cn1lib

I have also made some changes on the build server to add a more descriptive error message when it detects this scenario.  That will also be updated in the next build server update.